# Letting a user supply the name of a function via tkinter entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wrote this program in which I want the user to supply the name of a function which resides in a module (in a folder in his computer for example). For instance I have the function, 'my_sum' which resides in the module 'sum_functions.py' which in turn sits in the 'sum_package' folder. The idea is to use a ttk.Entry to get the function string and supply to 'import_func' which uses the importlib module and getattr to retrieve 'my_sum' . Finally I intend to pass my_sum() to calculate.
I get an error although the program prints 'my_sum' in the end. I would like to know What I  am doing wrong or if there is a better more pythonic way?

```
sum_package # resides in my computer
sum_function.py # resides in sum_package and contains my_sum.py

def my_sum(x, y): # actual function to be called
    return x * y

import importlib
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk 


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()
        

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self , width=12)
        self.entry.grid(row=3, column=1)
        load_func = ttk.Button(self, text="Load function", command =  self.import_func).grid(row=3, column=2)
        ttk.Button(self, text="Calculate",command=self.calculate).grid(column=3, row=3)
        self.quitButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.quit )

        self.quitButton.grid()

    def import_func(self, *args):
        global f # I made this global so the function could be accessed by other functions in the program
        try:
            value = str(self.entry.get())
            print(value)
            module_str = "sum_package." + 'sum_function' # get module str
            module = importlib.import_module(module_str)  # import module from str
            f = getattr(module, value)  # get function "function" in module
            return f
            
        except:
            pass

    def calculate(self, *args):
        global x, y 
        try:
            f(x, y)
        except ValueError:
            pass

app = Application()

app.master.title("Sample application") 
x, y = 5, 6
app.mainloop()

#Error
# Exception in Tkinter callback
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "/home/richard/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
#     return self.func(*args)
#   File "/home/richard/Dropbox/impedance_fitting_program/gui/test4.py", line 55, in calculate
#     f(x, y)
# NameError: name 'f' is not defined
# my_sum
```

Comment: Should you really be making modules based on user entry?

Comment: The user will have to define multiple models since data to be fitted varies from user to user and also they might want to try different models for a particular data So I expect that the function will be saved in a .py file. In matlab it is easy to save functions as a .m file and call the str2func. But python has no equivalent except the getattr. So i decided to explore this option

Comment: Whichever way i choose to make the app, the user still has to supply a function. So this is why I need to come up with the best approach. Still a beginner with tkinter btw.

Comment: The obvious way for this to fail would be if something before the `f = ...` assigment throws an exception. Have to checked that?

Comment: You are right @ Ture something was returning None. So I added a finally block i.e finally: return f and it is working now. But really I cant explain why adding the finally suddenly resolves the issue

Comment: Cannot reproduce error if `Load function` button is clicked before `Calculate` button.

Comment: Take a look at the eval expression

Comment: Thanks Jim,  I will take a look at the eval expression and see if it suits my purpose